# Difference between reverse and reverse_lazy in django

Tags: python, django

I learned about this `reverse_lazy` function in django fairly recently, but I can't seem to understand the difference between the `reverse` and `reverse_lazy` function.

For example, I have a CBV for deleting blog posts:

```
class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home.html')
```

What difference would it make if I just wrote `reverse` instead of `reverse_lazy`? I mean, both functions redirect us to a url. Then why do I need to use reverse_lazy in some places?

Comment: Lazy functions are evaluated as late as possible. Here a normal method would be evaluated once at class initiation time, a lazy one later everytime the `success_url` is used.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## using the named URL

```
reverse('news-archive')
```

passing a callable object

## (This is discouraged because you can't reverse namespaced views this way.)

```
reverse_lazy()
```

A lazily evaluated version of reverse().

reverse_lazy(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)¶
It is useful for when you need to use a URL reversal before your project’s URLConf is loaded. Some common cases where this function is necessary are:

providing a reversed URL as the url attribute of a generic class-based view.
providing a reversed URL to a decorator (such as the login_url argument for the django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required() decorator).
providing a reversed URL as a default value for a parameter in a function’s signature.